# How to compare AI model with other models for research purposes

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, model-comparison, research-design, maml

If I have X and Y datasets, I will apply meta-learning few-shot-learning by training the model on the X dataset and applying meta-testing using the Y dataset. While I compare my result with other state of the art methods, can I use their pre-trained model and test it on the Y dataset or do I have to train a model using their method on the X dataset and then test it on the Y dataset? Because the pre-trained models of other methods are trained on a different dataset not the X dataset.

I will compare my method with other few-shot learning methods for research purposes, but I don't know the right way. Thanks